# Do something after all threads finished python ( using t.start()! )

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is the code:

```
for tryproxy in proxy:
    threading.Thread(target=check, args=(tryproxy,)).start()
print("finished")
```

The problem is, even all threads finsished, it does not print out "finished".

Comment: What happens instead? What does "check" do?

Comment: It sends a request to a proxy judge website, if the proxy works it adds it to a txt file.

Comment: Does the program end without printing "finished", doesn't it end at all, prints it something else?

Comment: it ends without printing finished

Comment: So it prints nothing? The code should print "finished" nearly immediately at the beginning. Does something in your code change "sys.stdout"?

Comment: yes, you are right it prints it out in the beginning, i didn't notice that. but my gola is to print it out after the threads finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print out "finished" at the end you have to collect all thread objects in a list and wait for all of them to finish (using `join` method) before printing. This will look like:

```
threads = []

for tryproxy in proxy:
    t = threading.Thread(target=check, args=(tryproxy,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print("finished")
```